# Django postman use another User field as recipient identifier

Tags: python, django

I'm using [postman](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/wiki/Home) package for my `Django` application. Postman identifies recipients by their username field on User model - `User.username`.

I would like to change that to another field, something like `User.nickname`.

How can I do that?

My postman settings are below, but I can't find a way to change recipient field..

```
# Postman
POSTMAN_DISABLE_USER_EMAILING = True
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_ANONYMOUS = True
POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True
POSTMAN_SHOW_USER_AS = lambda u: u.member.nickname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.3.0 has a new setting for this purpose: `POSTMAN_NAME_USER_AS`.